# How to run a script shell just after the Dockerfile 'CMD ["mysqld"]'?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

I have a MariaDB image running on Docker container, which has to update its root password at each initialization, for security reasons. There is a vault server from which my container gets new password each time it initializes. After a new password is obtained, my script has to be run to login into MariaDB database and update the password. I have tried several strategies to run such script as soon as the MariaDB database is up and runnig, but no success up to now. I do use a Dockerfile to build my MariaDB extended image. At the end, there is a 'CMD ["mysqld"]' that starts up the service. The problem is that my script has to be run just after the "CMD ["mysqld"]" command, since it is the command that initializes MariaDB process and then the it becomes "Ready for connections".

Is there any way to workaround this situation in order to run my shell script (["/foreground.sh"]) just after MariaDB service is up and runnig? It is important to recall that no human manipulation is allowed after the container is initialized. Therefore, every action has to take place via script shell, since this project is for a production environment, from where I have no access.

## Relevant part of my Dockerfile

```
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
EXPOSE 3306
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY foreground.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh /foreground.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"] ["/foreground.sh"]
```

## Relevant part of my "foreground.sh"

```
    mysql -u"root" -p"$ROOT_PASSWORD" <<MariaDB_INPUT
    UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_NEW_VAULT") WHERE USER="root";
    UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("$MYSQL_PASSWORD_NEW_VAULT") WHERE USER="user";
    UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    quit
```

MariaDB_INPUT

Comment: Short form: Move `mysqld` *into* `foreground.sh` (typically -- starting it in the background, waiting for the service to become available, running your setup, then `wait`ing for that background service so your foreground task doesn't exit until the service does).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, first of all, thanks for your quick answer... The strategy you just suggested, I tried yesterday, but with no success. I got the following error messages.

`2019-06-11 23:18:02 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded`

`2019-06-11 23:18:02 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist`

`2019-06-11 23:18:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.`

`2019-06-11 23:18:02 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`

Comment: Moving it to be called directly rather than through a shell isn't going to fix those errors; the command runs with the same privileges either way.

Comment: @Charles, could you please give an example of it?

Comment: instead moving the `mysqld` into `foreground.sh`, move the `foreground.sh` into `docker-entrypoint.sh` script. If you will read it, you can see that this scripts take `mysqld` as argument, and run it differently. So change the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script to run the password change (or `foreground.sh` script)

Comment: @rom, thanks for your answer. However, the strategy you suggested was the one firstly tried, when the script was inside the docker-entrypoint.sh. Since such script is just successful applied just after mysqld service is up and running, I did create a foreground.sh file to be run just after mysqld service is initialized. For this reason, the question is about how to run such shell script file after MariaDB is initialized. I really would appreciate if you have any ideia about how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [official image for MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), you can just add your script to the folder `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*`.

Take a look in the [`docker-entrypoint.sh` script](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/c969655b3c92a1ae3f066e506ab7b32ff4ba4582/10.4/docker-entrypoint.sh):

- **Line 110** - the script is waiting for the instance to be running and accept queries.
- **Line 178** - the script runs customized scripts from the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*`

So you can just add your changing password script to the right place, and it will run after the instance is ready for updating the password. You don't have to change the `CMD` or the `ENTRYPOINT` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rom... I am trying this strategy, but it is not working so far. Just to recall here that when I change passwords in runtime using `UPDATE`, it works perfectly, however the problem persists when applying the same SQL scripts via `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`, but at least now it runs after MariaDB is up.

In the SQL script, If I use `UPDATE` or `ALTER` commands it returns sintax errors, and if I use `SET` It returns `proxies_priv` errors as follow below. 

`[Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@ae5131a14387' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.`

Comment: _**new_vault.sql**_

`UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("root-test") WHERE User="root";
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("pass-test") WHERE User="efaz";
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

_**Ouput Errors**_

`[Warning] ''user'' entry ''root@42bb3c6e2862'' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
[Warning] ''proxies_priv'' entry ''@% root@42bb3c6e2862'' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
Added new Master_info '''' to hash table
mysqld: ready for connections.`